# How to plot heat map in Seaborn with repeated Data?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have DataFrame in pandas and want to plot a heat map but I have repeated record  and seaborn can't deal with repeated data. my data frame:

```
                  From       To      Distance
            0   ABINGTON    AMBLER  10.0
            1   ABINGTON    BERKS COUNTY    42.0
            2   ABINGTON    BRIDGEPORT  19.0
            3   ABINGTON    BRYN ATHYN  6.0
            4   ABINGTON    BUCKS COUNTY    19.0
            5   ABINGTON    CHELTENHAM  4.0
            6   ABINGTON    CHESTER COUNTY  38.0
            7   ABINGTON    COLLEGEVILLE    30.0
            8   ABINGTON    CONSHOHOCKEN    16.0
            9   AMBLER  BERKS COUNTY    32.0
            10  AMBLER  BRIDGEPORT  12.0
            11  AMBLER  BRYN ATHYN  14.0
            12  AMBLER  BUCKS COUNTY    11.0
            13  AMBLER  CHELTENHAM  11.0
            14  AMBLER  CHESTER COUNTY  29.0
```

How I can plot heat map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the contrary, having "repeated data" like that which you provide actually lends itself well to pivoting, which is basically all you need to do to make heatmaps. Unless I misunderstand what you're trying to accomplish,

```
df_piv = df.pivot('From', 'To', 'Distance')
ax = sns.heatmap(df_piv)
plt.xticks(rotation=20)
```

will provide you with a heatmap of your data, where the gray boxes indicate missing values.

[image]

---

the pivoted dataframe looks like this,

```
In [14]: df_piv.T
Out[15]: 
From            ABINGTON  AMBLER
To                              
AMBLER              10.0     NaN
BERKS COUNTY        42.0    32.0
BRIDGEPORT          19.0    12.0
BRYN ATHYN           6.0    14.0
BUCKS COUNTY        19.0    11.0
CHELTENHAM           4.0    11.0
CHESTER COUNTY      38.0    29.0
COLLEGEVILL         30.0     NaN
CONSHOHOCKEN        16.0     NaN
```